# Why isn't this Perl code an error

Tags: syntax, perl

I'm writing a WxPerl program and instead of

```
$panel->SetDropTarget( MyTextDropTarget->new($panel) );
```

I wrote

```
$panel->SetDropTarget->( MyTextDropTarget->new($panel) );
```

and Perl didn't complain. (Perl called some function with some arguments, and the script did error out with an error message:

Usage: Wx::Window::SetDropTarget(THIS, target) at ./x.pl line 230.

### I'm curious as to how Perl parsed the 'wrong' version.

Added edit:

Okay, so if $x = \&some_function, then I understand why

```
$x->($arg1, $arg2, ...)
```

calls some_function($arg1, $arg2, .....).

runrig's example is one possibility, but I'm quite sure that:
1) $panel contains a blessed object reference, not a string.
2) SetDropTarget is a method (in a base class) of $panel.

From the error message we can assume that SetDropTarget() being called. If runrig's example still applies here (and I'd guess it does), then even though SetDropTarget isn't followed by parentheses, i.e. I have

```
$panel->SetDropTarget->
```

instead of

```
 $panel->SetDropTarget()->
```

Perl is still invoking SetDropTarget? (which inspects the number and type of its arguments and then fatally complains at runtime). Is that what happens?

Answer (score 6):

Because it's perfectly valid syntax. `$panel->SetDropTarget->( MyTextDropTarget->new($panel) )` means "Call the `&SetDropTarget` method from `$panel`, and then dereference the subref that `&SetDropTarget` returns." It's not what you meant to write, I'm guessing, but any error thrown would be at runtime, even in strict mode.

Comment: To add to what Richard Simões says: when a method takes no arguments, the parentheses are optional; that is, `$foo->bar()` can be written as `$foo->bar`. This is why `$panel->SetDropTarget->(...)` is taken to mean `$panel->SetDropTarget()->(...)`.

Answer (score 6):

Your SetDropTarget likely does not return a code reference, but you can't tell that until runtime:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $panel = 'main';

$panel->SetDropTarget->("bloomin'");

sub SetDropTarget {
  return sub { print "Set the $_[0] drop target!\n" }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl parsed

```
$panel->SetDropTarget->( MyTextDropTarget->new($panel) );
```

to mean "`$panel` is an object; call its `SetDropTarget` method (optional parenthesis omitted), which will return a reference to a `sub`; call that `sub`, passing the the result of `MyTextDropTarget->new($panel)` as its single parameter."

That is, Perl expected `SetDropTarget` to be something like `foo` in the following code:

```
sub foo {
    return sub {
        my $bar = shift;
        return $bar . ', world!'; 
    }
}

foo()->('Hello');
foo->('Goodby');
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is wrong - there are two function calls happening, not just one as you indicate. (see @runrig's example)

Comment: I would not say "a member", but "a method". And not "which itself is a reference to a sub", but "which returns a reference to a sub".